# Dynamic memory allocation in a cicle - c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic

What's the best way to dynamically allocate memory in a loop?

1.Free the memory every loop?

```
int *foo;
for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
{
    foo = new int [i];
    /*
    ...
    */
    delete foo;
 }
```

or

2.Free the memory in the end?

```
int *foo;
for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
{
    foo = new int [i];
    /*
    ...
    */
 }
 delete foo;
```

Comment: Don't use raw pointers. Use containers (e.g. `std::vector`) and/or smart pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 1: Multiple allocation / deallocation = bad performance

```
for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
{
    foo = new int [i];
    /*
    ...
    */
    delete[] foo;
}
```

Option 2: Multiple allocations / one deallocation = memory leak

```
int *foo;
for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
{
    foo = new int [i];
    /*
    ...
    */
}
delete[] foo;
```

Option 3: One allocation / one deallocation = OK if you need dynamic memory

```
int *foo = new int [10];
for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
{
    /*
    ...
    */
}
delete[] foo;
```

Option 4: Avoid dynamic allocation / deallocation

```
for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
{
  int foo[ i ];
    /*
    ...
    */
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason this has been voted down twice? It's not terrible advice. Especially if this needs to be used on a pre-c++11 environment.

Comment: Option 4 is not standard C++.

Comment: @sharth He wants to avoid dynamic allocation but advises the use of non-standard C++ in its place.

Comment: @chris: Compiler extensions will forever be the death of me.

Comment: @sharth, Well, C++ almost acquired them, too.

Answer (score 10):

First of all, when you use the `new[]` operator you need to match it with the `delete[]` operator, so you should do `delete[] foo`.

Secondly, if you do `delete[]` after the loop, you will only free the last memory you allocated, leading to memory leaks.

Thirdly, do you really *need* to use raw pointers? Can't you use e.g. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead?

Comment: the `delete[]` was my distraction

Comment: For an array of 10 int, _if_ performance is an issue, I'd just use `int foo[10];`.  Inside or outside the loop; it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

- In your first example, you have undefined behavior, you need to use `delete[]` to delete an array allocated by `new []`
- In your second example, same issue, but even if you fix it you will have a memory leak, since only the last allocated array will be deleted.

---

**Solution:**

- The best way is to use a standard container :

E.g.:

```
std::vector<int>
std::array<int, 10>
```

- Or you can still use a smart pointer :

Example:

```
for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
{
    auto foo = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int [i]);
    /*
    ...
    */
 };
```

- Or, if you really cant, then make sure that each call to `new[]` is matched by a call to `delete[]`

Answer (score 1):

The first example is better, though you should call:

```
delete [] foo;
```

To free the entire block.

Your second example is a memory leak.  Here's why:

During the first iteration, memory is allocated and foo is set to point to the start of the allocated buffer.  Every iteration after the first, the memory which was allocated in the previous iteration is not being freed.  Instead, foo is just being set to point to a newly allocated buffer.  After that, there is no longer any way to reference the previously allocated buffer.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no good solution using `new`, period.  The
argument would be a new `std::vector` each time in the loop,
versus one outside of the loop, with a `resize` each time
through the loop:

```
std::vector<int> foo;
for ( int i = 1; i < 10; ++ i ) {
    foo.resize( i );
    //  ...
}
```

vs.

```
for ( int i = 1; i < 10; ++ i ) {
    std::vector<int> foo( i );
    //  ...
}
```

If you're doing any real work in the loop, the difference is
likely not to be significant, however...

You can improve the first version by using reserve:

```
std::vector<int> foo;
foo.reserve( 10 );
for ( int i = 1; i < 10; ++ i ) {
    foo.resize( i );
    //  ...
}
```

If the rest of the loop is pretty trivial, this could be faster.
For that matter, if the maximum size is known and isn't too big,
you can use:

```
int foo[10];
for ( int i = 1; i < 10; ++ i ) {
    //  ...
}
```

In a lot of cases, this is perfectly acceptable, and it will be
the fastest (although again, most of the time, the performance
difference will be negligible, and you'll loose the advantages
of `std::vector`—which in most cases, includes bounds
checking when optimization isn't active).

Comment: my question was focused on where to delete the pointer but I've learn something with your answer!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is best to avoid what you are currently trying to do, use a vector. However, if this is purely for a learning exercise, I would recommend storing each pointer (new int[]) in an array. The reason for this, if it is not clear at this point, is because you keep assigning a new pointed at array in memory, then lose the reference of it by assigning new memory to the same pointer without calling delete[].

With a bit better design, you could, as I mentioned prior, is to store an array of such pointers e.g. *foo -- then you can clean up memory in the destructor ~Foo(). Just an idea.